# Mapping MySql Decimal to Java

Tags: java, mysql

According to this:

http://alvinalexander.com/java/mysql-to-java-field-mappings-decimal-bigdecimal-scala

You should map MySql's `decimal` to Java's `BigDecimal`. However, a table in my db contains a column of type `decimal(10,8)` (for longitude and latitude). Am I still supposed to use `BigDecimal` somehow for the mapping?

Comment: Yes you can. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Since it seems like a 2 dimentional type in the db and I'm not sure how its in Java.

Comment: How can longitude and latitude fit in a `decimal(8,10)`? Maximum value is `0.0099999999`.

Comment: Not sure about that Andreas.. I just got the db as it is like that. If its indeed an error then we'll fix the value issue later. For now the mapping is the important thing :)

Comment: That's not even a valid type definition according to [MySQL's manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html): *The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D). The ranges of values for the arguments in MySQL 5.7 are as follows: M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1 to 65. D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.* 10 should be no larger than 8. A decimal is a decimal. It's not a 2 dimensional type.

Comment: JB sorry my bad.. its (10,8). Edited

Comment: but it seems like you have answered my question. You can copy your comment to an answer (just remove the part about the order of the numbers) and I'll accept it.

Comment: Actually, since your problem is essentially a typo, there is a closure reason for Questions that are just typos ....

Comment: No, my problem was not a typo.. How does the typo relate to mapping between objects??

Comment: How do you represent latitude and longitude (2 dimensional type) as a single number in the database?

Answer (score -3):

Mysql Decimal --> Java data type, use BigDecimal from java.ma